# It there a way to manage angular routes at compile time?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

For an advanced beginner in Ng like myself, debugging angular routes is done run-time. I am looking for a solution to have a higher confidence in the consistency at compile time.

### Situation

Managing a Ng route means managing an objet with 3 parts

- path
- component
- outlet

For each route, depending on what part to change, there are maintenance points to manage the 3 parts consistently.

1. in typescript app-routing.module.ts that set up routes

```
 ...
  // foo routes
  { path: 'book-adder', component: BookAdderComponent, outlet: 'foo' },
  { path: 'book-detail/:id', component: BookDetailComponent, outlet: 'foo' },

  { path: 'editor-adder', component: EditorAdderComponent , outlet: 'foo'},
  { path: 'editor-detail/:id', component: EditorDetailComponent, outlet: 'foo' },
...
```

2. in the html template that declares the router outlets

```html
...
<router-outlet name="foo"></router-outlet>
...
```

3. in the calls to navigate in the controlers

```
...
  setDetailOutlet(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate([{
      outlets: {
        foo: ["book-detail", id]
      }
    }]);
  }
...
```

### Problem

- to rename the router outlet part (from "foo" to "bar" for instance), one have to manualy change the code at the three maintenance points.
- to rename the path, one have to manualy change the code at two maintenance points.
- to manage the component part, one have to manualy change the app-routing.module.ts and the code in the calling component

### Question

- is there a solution to centralize the solution in order to minimize mainenance points for each route ?

Answer (score 0):

The Best way to do so, i would say to use `Auth guards from angular`.

But to answer your question try

`<!-- Since you cannot bind [name] property and throw you error -->
<router-outlet name="{{outletName}}"></router-outlet>`

use outletName from the component where you are calling the code from.